# Using an external redirect URI with Google's OAuth2 for desktop apps

Tags: c#, wpf, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a desktop WPF app that has to link to a user's Google account in order to integrate with Google Drive later. I'm Using their `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2` utility to handle authorization.
I've registered my app in Google console and added OAuth2 client ID for a `Desktop app` as per documentation.

My problem is, I don't see where in the console I can add/whitelist a custom redirect URI for my app to use - this option seems to be only available to Web applications, and my desktop app has no  other option than to redirect to `localhost`, which is not acceptable. I've tried overriding `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` and passing my URI directly into

```
public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
        => new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
        {
            ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
            Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
            RedirectUri = _customRedirectUri,
            State = _state
        };
```

But Google spits out a **redirect_uri_mismatch** of course, because why wouldn't it - I couldn't add it anywhere else. I've implemented the same functionality for DropBox integration, where you can specify and whitelist a redirect page - I assumed Google would have something similar, but the `Authorized Redirect URI` field isn't even there for desktop apps.

Information on this seems to be very scarce. Is this at all possible and what am I missing ?

Comment: Hello @Teacan, does [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#creatingcred) provide any help to your question? Cheers!

Comment: I've used this documentation as reference while trying to make this work to no avail. But this made me look once again. I've just tried to use a different type of credentials (Web app), where I could add my redirect URI - and it worked ! This part of documentation is a little misleading though - if you want this functionality in your desktop app, you have to pick Web type, not Desktop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a last ditch effort, I've created credentials of a different type (Web app), where I could provide my redirect URI and it worked this way. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#creatingcred) is a bit confusing in this regard though. It suggests using a `Desktop` profile for such apps, but you have no choice for redirect pages in that case.

Comment: What URI did you use? My mismatch is spitting up an IP address but the port keeps changing, so updating my desktop app to Web app still doesn't work for authorization.

Comment: But then we have to include the client secret in the app.